# F# - How to properly implement Setup and initialize variables with NUnit

Tags: unit-testing, f#

I'm doing my first dive into F# at work, and I'm moving several C# unit tests I have to F# as an exercise. Our tests are quite complex, but I relish the challenge (With setups, inheritance, teardowns and so on).

As I've been seeing, mutability should be avoided if possible, but when writing the `[SetUp]` parts of the tests I can't seem to find a way to jump over mutability. Example that creates a dummy XML for a test::

```
[<TestFixture>]
type CaseRuleFixture() = 

    [<DefaultValue>] val mutable xsl : XNamespace
    [<DefaultValue>] val mutable simpleStylesheet : XElement
    [<DefaultValue>] val mutable testNode : XElement
    [<DefaultValue>] val mutable rootNode : XElement
    [<DefaultValue>] val mutable root : XElement

    let CreateXsltHeader(xsl: XNamespace) =
        // Build XSLT header
        let styleSheetRoot = 
            new XElement(
                xsl + "stylesheet", 
                new XAttribute(XName.Get "version", "1.0"), 
                new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsl", "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"), 
                new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "msxsl", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"),
                new XAttribute(XName.Get "exclude-result-prefixes", "msxsl"),
                new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "utils", "urn:myExtension"))

        let outputNode = 
            new XElement(
                xsl + "output", 
                new XAttribute(XName.Get "method", "xml"), 
                new XAttribute(XName.Get "indent", "yes"))

        styleSheetRoot.Add outputNode
        styleSheetRoot


    [<SetUp>]
    member this.SetUp() =
        this.xsl <- XNamespace.Get "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        this.simpleStylesheet <- CreateXsltHeader(this.xsl)

        Directory.EnumerateFiles "Templates"
        |> Seq.iter(fun filepath -> this.simpleStylesheet.Add(XElement.Parse(File.ReadAllText filepath).Elements()))

        let variable = 
            new XElement(
                this.xsl + "variable", 
                new XAttribute(XName.Get "name", "ROOT"), 
                new XAttribute(XName.Get "select", "ROOT"))

        this.simpleStylesheet.Add(variable)

        let rootTemplate = new XElement(this.xsl + "template", new XAttribute(XName.Get "match", "/ROOT"))
        this.simpleStylesheet.Add(rootTemplate);

        this.rootNode <- new XElement(XName.Get "ROOT")
        rootTemplate.Add(this.rootNode);

        this.root <- new XElement(XName.Get "ROOT")
        this.testNode <- new XElement(XName.Get "TESTVALUE")

        this.root.Add(this.testNode)

    [<Test>]
    member this.CaseCapitalizeEachWordTest() =
        this.testNode.Value <- " text to replace ";

        let replaceRule = new CaseRule();
        replaceRule.Arguments <- [| "INITIALS" |];
        this.rootNode.Add(
            replaceRule.ApplyRule [| new XElement(this.xsl + "value-of", new XAttribute(XName.Get "select", "TESTVALUE")) |]);

        let parser = new XsltParserHelper(this.simpleStylesheet);
        let result = parser.ParseXslt(this.root);

        let value = result.DescendantsAndSelf() |> Seq.find(fun x -> x.Name = XName.Get "ROOT")

        Assert.AreEqual(" Text To Replace ", value.Value)
```

Those `[<DefaultValue>] val mutable` to declare the variables (without initializing because that's SetUp job) and make those variables available to all the class scope, and the fact that I've basically done a 1:1 translation from what I had in C# without any apparent gaining in syntax and readability gave me the chills. Is there any way to rewrite these kind of tests and setups that looks nicer? Because all examples I've seen all over internet are simple, small and do not cover these cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's reduce the problem to a more manageable size first:

## Reduced problem

In this test, you have two mutable fields being initialized in the `SetUp` method:

```
[<TestFixture>]
type MutableTests() = 
    [<DefaultValue>] val mutable foo : int
    [<DefaultValue>] val mutable bar : int

    [<SetUp>]
    member this.SetUp () =
        this.foo <- 42
        this.bar <- 1337

    [<Test>]
    member this.TheTest () = 
        Assert.AreEqual(42, this.foo)
        Assert.AreEqual(1337, this.bar)
```

Obviously, this is a stand-in for the real problem.

## Functions that return values

Instead of setting class fields, why not write functions that initialize the values that you need?

```
module BetterTests =
    let createDefaultFoo () = 42
    let createDefaultBar () = 1337

    [<Test>]
    let ``a test using individual creation functions`` () =
        let foo = createDefaultFoo ()
        let bar = createDefaultBar ()

        Assert.AreEqual(42, foo)
        Assert.AreEqual(1337, bar)
```

If you wan't *all* the values at once (like you have access to all fields from within a class), you can define a single function that returns all values in a tuple or record:

```
    let createAllDefaultValues () = createDefaultFoo (), createDefaultBar ()

    [<Test>]
    let ``a test using a single creation function`` () =
        let foo, bar = createAllDefaultValues ()

        Assert.AreEqual(42, foo)
        Assert.AreEqual(1337, bar)
```

This example uses an `int * int` tuple, but it might be more readable to define a record:

```
    type TestValues = { Foo : int; Bar : int }

    let createDefaultTestValues () = {
        Foo = createDefaultFoo ()
        Bar = createDefaultBar () }

    [<Test>]
    let ``a test using a single creation function that returns a record`` () =
        let defaultValues = createDefaultTestValues ()

        Assert.AreEqual(42, defaultValues.Foo)
        Assert.AreEqual(1337, defaultValues.Bar)
```

Notice that, unlike classes in C#, records in F# are super-lightweight to declare.

If you want to learn more about idiomatic unit testing with F#, a good place to start could be [my Pluralsight course about *unit testing with F#*](http://bit.ly/1JhEbA7).

Comment: I really like your solution and indeed it's way better than the mutable approach, but... by not using SetUp, wouldn't you have to duplicate the piece of code "let defaultValues = createDefaultTestValues ()" on all your tests to somehow simulate the SetUp? I ask this because AFAIK duplicate items is kind of a code smell.

Thank you!

Comment: @DavidJiménezMartínez Yes, you would have to duplicate that single method call, but consider this: could the fact that you implicitly have access to all class fields hide a design (and maintainability) problem with the tests? Do *all* the tests use *all* the class fields? In my career, I've seen innumerable example of test classes with too many fields that half of the tests don't use. Should you accept such a class design in 'production' code? I don't think you should, so neither should you accept it in test code: you have to maintain the test code as well.

Comment: @DavidJiménezMartínez Apart from that, even in OOP, [Implicit Setup](http://xunitpatterns.com/Implicit%20Setup.html) is ambiguous at best. While the benefit is a slight reduction of DRY, the disadvantages are more numerous: coupling, cohesion, and explicitness all suffer. Personally, I never use this 'pattern'.

Comment: Thanks for all your comprehensive answers, @Mark!